# How do I install a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: linux, firefox, greasemonkey

I'm using Firefox 57 and Greasemonkey 4.0 on Linux. I navigate to file:///home/pts/Downloads/foo.user.js . The correct file shows up with a fixed-width font in the browser window. The script installation dialog doesn't appear.

Opening the *foo.user.js* file in *File / Open* doesn't help, the same happens as when I type the URL above.

Please note that it's not possible to create a new userscript manually, because e.g. the *New User Script* menu item (recommended at http://hayageek.com/greasemonkey-tutorial/) doesn't exist for me.

Tampermonkey isn't any better: it gives me the error message *Tampermonkey has no permission to access local files!*.

How do I install this Greasemonkey script *without* uploading it to any webserver?

Comment: What makes you think you have a compatible Greasemonkey plugin properly installed?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47296202/how-do-you-create-a-new-script-in-greasemonkey

Comment: Short answer: You don't. Switch to Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey.

Comment: @Basilevs: Tools / Add-ons displays Greasemonkey 4.0 as installed and working, and I'm able to it using the monkey icon on the toolbar.

Comment: @BrockAdams: Tampermonkey isn't any better: it gives me the error message *Tampermonkey has no permission to access local files!*.

Comment: @pts, that's actually a FF 57 problem, not a TM problem.  One of many reasons why I suggest switching browsers.  If you stay with FF 57, at least TM makes it easy to cut-n-paste in your new script.